# Is the villain from the new Dragon Ball movie using Freezer army or saiyan armor?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

So this is an image of the new villain from the new Dragon Ball movie. Can it be confirmed it's using Freezer army or saiyan armor?

[image]

The full trailer for more details is here [Trailer new Dragon Ball movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0A0Rp45wTs)

Comment: weren't the Sayians using Frieza Army armor anyway?

Comment: @Memor-X Not 100% sure if they are exactly the same or a bit different. May be someone can tell the difference between Freezer army armor and saiyan armor. BTW, the question goes as if it's Freezer army armor, saiyan armor, any of them because they are the same, or there are no enough details to assure it's any of them

Comment: The trailer doesn't have sufficient information to come to a definite conclusion. Hence the answers to the same would be solely out of opinions. So I suggest, this question be closed.

Comment: hey, don't rely only in the info or sources I post (such as the trailer), if I ask a question it's because I dont know all the info and in hopes someone else does and can answer it. I just found it's confirmed it's a saiyan https://twitter.com/debaoki/status/976178624687628288/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fcomicbook.com%2Fanime%2F2018%2F03%2F20%2Fdragon-ball-super-movie-villain-past-future-timeline%2F . So there any of you can answer the question , I dont want to answer it myself. BTW, if you dont know the answer, it doesnt necessarily means there is no answer

Comment: @Pablo Your question wasn't about him being a Saiyan. It was about him wearing Saiyan armor or Freiza's armor. That cannot be answered definitely. As all Saiyan's wore Freiza's armor while they were under him. Saiyan armor is a tad bit different. Then again, that would be answers based on opinions and not actual reasoning.